# Javascript incorporating jquery not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

So I have been working on writing a script that takes in input from 10 different fields and if anything on the dropdown is changed a popScore and popLevel gets updated accordingly. I ran into a little issue with it producing a number with like 10 decimals so I had to round it to 2. The javascript works on all browsers except Internet Explorer. **What causes it to fail on Internet Explorer?**

Below I included the javascript for only one of the dropdowns to save space but the difference between them is the values for the popScore and the number of items in the dropdown. The popLevel can only go up to 5.

Any help on understanding why it doesn't work is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  //global variables
  var popLevel = 0;
  var popScore = 0.00;
  var q1=0;
  var q2=0;
  var q3=0;
  var q4=0;
  var q5=0;
  var q6=0;
  var q7=0;
  var q8=0;
  var q9=0;
  var q10=0;
$('.selectionbox1').change(function() {
    if(q1 != 0){
        if(q1 == 1){
        popScore = popScore - 0.13;
        }
        else if(q1 == 2){
        popScore = popScore - 0.25;
        }
        else if(q1 == 3){
        popScore = popScore - 0.38;
        }
        else if(q1 == 4){
        popScore = popScore - 0.50;
        }
        else if(q1 == 5){
        popScore = popScore - 0.63;
        }
    }
    var b = document.getElementById("q1").value;
    if(b == 1){
        popScore = popScore + 0.13;
    }
    else if(b == 2){
        popScore = popScore + 0.25;
        }
    else if(b == 3){
        popScore = popScore + 0.38;
    }
    else if(b == 4){
        popScore = popScore + 0.50;
        }
    else if(b == 5){
        popScore = popScore + 0.63;
    }

    if(popScore > 4.00){
    popLevel=5;
    }
    else if(popScore > 3.00){
    popLevel=4;
    }
    else if(popScore > 2.00){
    popLevel=3;
    }
    else if(popScore > 1.00){
    popLevel=2;
    }
    else if(popScore > 0.00){
    popLevel=1;
    }

    //record the current value of the field changed
    var e = document.getElementById("q1");
    q1=e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    //round to 2 decimal places for score
    popScore = parseFloat(popScore.toFixed(2));

    //update the fields for pop score and pop level
    var txt = document.getElementById("popLevel");
    txt.innerHTML=popLevel;
    var txt2 = document.getElementById("popScore");
    txt2.innerHTML=popScore;
});
```

Comment: Which Version of IE and what is the error that you get?

Comment: Some suggestions to improve your code. Use an array `q` instead of individual variables. Also, set up an array or a map (let's say `value`), where `1` maps to `0.13`, `2` maps to `0.25` and so on. Then all you need to do is `popScore = popScore - value[q[1]];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floating numbers are not exact. You should always round them for display purposes. When I type `2.48+1.49` on my JS console in chrome, I get `3.9699999999999998`. This is true for any language that uses http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754, which is the most widely used floating point format.

Here's a good explanation of the problem: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html It's for Python, but like I mentioned before, most languages use the same format.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. He's using `toFixed(2)`.

Comment: @VivinPaliath OP is using `toFixed(2)` because of the floating point approximation, but OP would prefer not having to round it. My answer explains that you must round it.

Comment: I tried to round but the only way I figured to do so was using `toFixed(2)`

Comment: @JuanMendes Ah, I thought he was saying that `toFixed(2)` wasn't working on IE. My mistake!

Comment: @fudge22it `toFixed` does round it to the number of decimals requested. There is nothing you can do besides what you are already doing. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was confused about the `3.999999999998` thing. Either way I figured out the problem so it's working now. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @fudge22it What do you mean you figured out the problem? Was it something besides what I said? If so, you should add an answer with the correct solution. Otherwise, you should accept this as the correct answer.